# How do I use the Monitor class to make async behavior seem syncrounous?

Tags: .net, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm writing an application that loads some javascript into a WebBrowser object.  To prevent this from getting loaded and the lag associated with it, I am initializing it on the main UI thread when my app loads and keeping a static reference to it.

The problem comes when I have other threads that want to use it.  Thus, I am trying to use the Monitor class to help me out.

On the main thread I have

```
public static readonly WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
private static readonly object syncObject = new object();
```

when the other threads call it, I have the following function.

```
public static string GetDataFromJs(string key)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    if (isInitialized == true)
    {
        try
        {
            webBrowser.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    result = (string)webBrowser.InvokeScript("getData", key);
                    //TODO: pulse monitor object.
                });

            //TODO: wait for monitor object to get pulsed.
            return result;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do from here?  I've tried Monitor.Wait/Enter and Monitor.Pulse in thier respective comment areas, but I keep getting Syncronization exceptions.

Thanks!

Comment: I feel like a moron lol... forgot to put it all inside a lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static string GetDataFromJs(string key) 
{ 
    string result = string.Empty;

```
if (isInitialized == true) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        webBrowser.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            { 

                lock(syncObject)
                {
                     result = (string)webBrowser.InvokeScript("getData", key); 
                     Monitor.Pulse(syncObject);
                }
            }); 

        lock(syncObject)
        {
             Monitor.Wait(syncObject);
        }

        return result; 
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) 
    { 
        return string.Empty; 
    } 
}
return string.Empty;
```

}

Make sure this is right :)